# Access current frame number during animation via Python API

Tags: python

I'm setting a Noise Texture node with W value to be linked to frame number (see picture). The idea is that generating noise as the result of the frame number * a coefficient (0.005).

I can make it via the Shaded Editor.

[image: I need to replicate this in Python API]

However, due to scalability I have to find a way to code it via the Python API.
My script is the following

```
NoiseTextureStar = starMaterialNodeTree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexNoise")
NoiseTextureStar.noise_dimensions = '4D'
NoiseTextureStar.inputs[2].default_value = 102.800
NoiseTextureStar.inputs[3].default_value = 2.200
NoiseTextureStar.inputs[5].default_value = 0.261
NoiseTextureStar.inputs[5].default_value = 4
```

My first attempt was to include the following line:

```
NoiseTextureStar.inputs[1].default_value = #frame*0.0005
```

but:

1. "#" is escaped as a comment character in Python, and
2. you can't multiply a string by a float.

Therefore, I'm looking for a way to read the current frame number **while animating** and use it a variable in Python.

My first attempt:

```
currentFrame = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].frame_current
```

was unsuccessful because my Python script only read the first frame when executed.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
fcurve = NoiseTextureStar.inputs[1].driver_add('default_value')
fcurve.driver.expression = 'frame * 0.0005'
```

[Search for "add driver python"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=add%20driver%20python)